# How to set JSON string obtained from Angular in java Object in spring

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am using WebSocket for making a chat application.

This is the code of my Angular for sending a `MessageModel` object to backend after converting it into JSON string.

```
sendMessage(message: MessageModel){
let data = JSON.stringify({
  message: message
})    
this.ws.send("/messaging/"+message.receiverId, {}, data); }
```

Now my Java code for receiving the message is:

```
@MessageMapping("/messaging/{to}")
@SendTo("/inbox/coversation/{to}")
public String processMessageFromClient(@DestinationVariable String to, @Payload String message) throws Exception {
    MessageModel msg = new MessageModel();
    System.out.println(message);

    msg = new Gson().fromJson(message, MessageModel.class);
    System.out.println(msg);

    return message;
}
```

**OUTPUT of System.out.println(message) is**:

```
{"message":{"messageText":"hey","senderId":4,"senderName":"Akash Malhotra","receiverId":1,"senderEmail":"aku@gmail.com","sentTime":"15:19:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","date":"08/06/2020, 15:19:43"}}
```

and

**OUTPUT of System.out.println(msg) is:**

```
MessageModel [messageText=null, senderName=null, senderId=null, senderEmail=null, profilePicUrl=null, receiverId=null, sentTime=null, date=null]
```

QUESTION: The thing I am searching for is a method to set my 'String message' received from angular to my MessageModel object in java since It is showing all the null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL/DR This works

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public String processMessageFromClient( String to, String message ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( message );

        final MessageWrapper msg = new Gson().fromJson( message, MessageWrapper.class );
        System.out.println( msg.message );

        return message;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        final String jsonString = "{\"message\":{\"messageText\":\"hey\",\"senderId\":4,\"senderName\":\"Akash Malhotra\",\"receiverId\":1,\"senderEmail\":\"aku@gmail.com\",\"sentTime\":\"15:19:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)\",\"date\":\"08/06/2020, 15:19:43\"}}";
        new StackOverflow().processMessageFromClient( "You", jsonString );
    }
}

class MessageModel
{
    String messageText;
    String senderName;
    Integer senderId;
    String senderEmail;
    String profilePicUrl;
    Integer receiverId;
    String sentTime;
    String date;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // ... etc.
    }
}

class MessageWrapper
{
    MessageModel message;
}
```

### Breakdown:

The JSON string contains another wrapper, in the form of:

```
{
    "message" = { /* actual MessageModel contents */ }
}
```

and since the MessageModel does not contain a field `message`, no fields are set, resulting in `null` values.
Wrapping the MessageModel in another class `MessageWrapper` that *does* have a field `message` of type `MessageModel`, allows GSON to recursively decode the `MessageModel`.

Comment: You're welcome :)
If this answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted, so that other people with the same question can find it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass MessageModel in your method instead of a String. Spring will try to use the underlying jackson (or a custom mapper your set for spring to use) to map the payload to a MessageModel object using the MessageModel  class.

```java
@MessageMapping("/messaging/{to}")
@SendTo("/inbox/coversation/{to}")
public String processMessageFromClient(@DestinationVariable String to, @Payload MessageModel message) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```